# Sencha ajax call failing on device

Tags: ajax, post, extjs, cordova

A am trying to make a fairly simple ajax call to my server to handle login etc. the app is written using sencha, with phonegap.  As far as I am aware, because phonegap sends all requests as file// cross-domain issues do not apply.  However I am constantly getting failures when testing this on a real device.  If I implement the sencha app as localhost then everything works fine (this is making a call to a different server).  The call is successful etc.  However when I build it in eclipse and port it to my phone, I always get a failure.  the code I am using is below, but I don't think it is this because as I say, this works locally.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://xxx/global/external_api.ashx',
    timeout: 3000,
    method: 'POST',
    params: requestData,
    success: function (xhr) {
        alert('Success: ');
    },
    failure: function (e) {
        alert("An error occured connecting to the server: ");
    }
});
```

Anyone have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be something to do with the newest 3.2 build.. reverted to 2.9 and it works fine.